# Concatenate int and FILE* (C/C++)

Tags: c, file-descriptor

I would like to name my file descriptors, fp,  based on the index of the for loop. For instance,

```
char* fbad[4]= "fbad";
char* mod[3]="mod";

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
  sprintf(fbad_file, "%s%s%d", fbad,mod,i);
  FILE *fp = fopen(fbad_file, "w");  ////????????????
  /*then do stuff here*/
  fclose(fp);
}
```

How does one concatenate *fp and i such shat the descriptor is unique for every file opened? For example, what I want to achieve is:     for i=6, FILE *fp6.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `char* fbad[4] = "fbad";` does not do what you think. `char fbad[4] = "fbad";` doesn't either.

Comment: char *fbad = "fbad";  
char fbad [] = { "fbad" };
char fbad[5] = { "fbad" };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`For example, what I want to achieve is: for i=6, FILE *fp6.`

Use an array:

```
FILE *fp[10];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    fp[i] = fopen(...);
}
```

Although, if you are closing the file pointer inside of the for-loop, what is the problem with reusing `fp`?

Comment: Thanks @cegfault. You made a good point on the final question. As a follow up question therefore, if file pointer is not to be closed inside the for-loop, is it correct to: 

    int functionName() {
      //do definitions and initializations here
    
      FILE *fp[10];
      for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        fp[i] = fopen(...);
       }

      // do your stuff here

      fclose(fp[0]);
      fclose(fp[1]);
      fclose(fp[2]); 
      fclose(fp[3]);
      return 0;
    }

Comment: yes, that is would be technically correct.  Of course it depends on what exactly you are doing.  If you are only using one file at a time, I would personally do it all inside the for loop.  However, if you are using multiple files at the same time (eg, copying or comparing), then I would do as you just did.